# Javascript to jQuery Conversion for an xml ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following script

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", "/getSelectedProductData?offerCollectionRef=" + offerCollectionRef + "&brandRef=" + brandRef + "&priceRef=" + priceRef + "&defaultSmallImage=" + defaultSmallImage + "&offerCode=" + offerCode + "&index=" + index, false);    

xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

I know how to write a `$.ajax` in jQuery. But I am stuck at how to send data.

My questions are

1. The return is XML and so the `dataType: xml`. am I correct?
2. How should I pass the data to the url?

Please elaborate on these things.
Disclaimer: The thing is that I couldn't test it myself and so this question.

Comment: so, does the code you already have work? If so, why are you changing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1 The return is XML and so the dataType: xml. am I correct?

You actually don;t need to specify it if the server sets proper Content-Type header to `text/xml`. jQuery will automatically consider the result as XML

> 2 How should I pass the data to the url?

You could use the `data` hash:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/getSelectedProductData',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'xml', // not necessary if the server sets the Content-Type: text/xml response header
    data: { 
        offerCollectionRef: offerCollectionRef,  
        brandRef: brandRef,
        priceRef: priceRef,
        defaultSmallImage: defaultSmallImage,
        offerCode: offerCode,
        index: index
    },
    success: function(xml) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Also you seem to be sending a synchronous request by setting the async parameter to false. To emulate the same with jQuery you could add the `async: false` option. This being said, you probably shouldn't be doing it. SJAX (sync javascript) will block the browser during the request and ruin the user experience.

Comment: You can also set `data` to a querystring. The above method is certainly easier to read and debug, though.

Comment: @mblase75, you can but you shouldn't as your parameters won't be properly url encoded. What if the offerCollectionRef variable equals for example to `'foo&bar=baz'` This will totally ruin the request? So you should always use the data hash and never use string concatenations when dealing with urls.

Comment: Darin: thanks for clarifying. I didn't say the querystring was a GOOD option, just that it was an option.

Comment: @mblase75, sure, it is an option. It's just important when you propose *an option* like this to specify that it should never be used because someone having the same problem in the future might read this post and actually use it.

Comment: thanks darin. i was reading about the dataType *Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)* now i get what the intelligent guess is. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

1. Yep.
2. You can use the `data` property when passing settings to `$.ajax()`. It can be an object (it will be converted to a query string) or a query string. Please check the jQuery Manual for further details.

Excerpt from the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> **data (Object, String)** Data to be sent to the server. It is
>   converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to
>   the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this
>   automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an
>   Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the
>   value of the traditional setting (described below).

So from your example, `url` shall be `'/getSelectedProductData'`, and `data` could be everything after `?`. Or you can organize them into an object like `{ 'offerCollectionRef': offerCollectionRef, ... }`, it is a bit more readable.